# Generated url's are seems to be wrong

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I created an application with signalR references in visual studio.
Created a hub. When running application on IIS Express, everything works
fine. When I transfer it to IIS8, in firebug I see that URL's of signalR are wrong,
for instance:

```
http://localhost/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=......
```

The problem that there is a missing site name, should be:

```
http://localhost/MYSITE/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=......
```

This is the script I am using to init connection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var proxy;

        $(function () {
            var connection = $.hubConnection();
            proxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
            proxy.on('newMessage', onNewMessage);
            connection.start();

            $('#send').click(onSend);
        });

        function onNewMessage(message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + $('#message').val() + '</li>');
        }

        function onSend() {
            proxy.invoke('newMessage', $().val());
        }
    </script>
```

I tried to send connection to $.hubConnection(), but then site name is getting doubled:

```
http://localhost/MYSITE/MYSITE/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=......
```

Comment: What does your code look like for the `<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a tilde to refer to the application root directory when including scripts/other resources. I have a similar setup and this works for me in development and production environments:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No, unfortunate its not the problem, this is the set:
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0-rc1.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script> By the way, it happens with version 1.1.3 as well.

Comment: @eddyuk your "/signalr/hubs" JavaScript doesn't have a tilde in front of it.

Comment: Also, I just learned that if I use proxyless connection, I don't need ~/signalr/hubs in my code. And it is working with IIS express. As I go IIS7.5 or 8, for some reason it goes to localhost/signalr without application name.

Comment: Just for kicks, what's your application_start method look like in your global.asax file? You need to call "RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()" before any other routing calls in application_start.